# Why do I need to configure network settings for both an ECS cluster and an ECS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When I create an ECS cluster to run on EC2s, there is the option "Network settings for Amazon EC2 instances", where I can choose a VPC, subnets and security groups.

Then, when I create a service, there is the option "Networking", where I can again choose a VPC, subnets and security groups.

If my tasks are going to run on my EC2 instances and I already configured the network options when I created the cluster, why do I have to configure them again when I create the service?

**Update:**

I just tried the options "capacity provider strategy" and "launch type ec2". Actually, when I first select them, the option "Networking" is not there. But when I choose my task definition, the "Networking" option appears.

Here is the task definition I'm using:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:---:task-definition/test-django:3",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "test-django",
            "image": "---.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test-django:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "test-django-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/test-django",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "family": "test-django",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::---:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 3,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "512",
    "memory": "512",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2024-01-25T12:10:34.018Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::---:user/admin",
    "tags": []
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77808682/13070

Answer (score 0):

In the service creation on compute configuration you can choose 2 options:

- capacity provider strategy
- launch type

if you choose launch type ec2, the interface doesnt show any networking configuration because the tasks are going to register in any ec2 with enough resources that are registered in the cluster.

if you choose capacity provider strategy and you created an autoscaling group and a capacity provider it doesnt show any networking configuration, because the networking configuration is taken from autoscaling group (which is usually created during the cluster creation)

perhaps you are selecting fargate instead of your default capacity provider?

Comment: I just tried both options: "capacity provider strategy" and "launch type ec2". Actually, when I first select them, the option "Networking" is not there. But when I choose my task definition, "Networking" appears. I will include my task definition in the question. Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Right, this is making me think that is posible to register ec2 of diferents vpcs on the same ecs cluster, and showing the networking configuration when you select an ec2 task allows you to select where to scale your tasks. But not sure

Comment: It turned out that I can configure "Networking" when I create a service because the "networkMode" is set "awsvpc". When this option is chosen, an ENI is created for each task. Once I switched the "networkMode" to "bridge", the "Networking" option disappeared.